# jenkins maven c Cannot run program "link"

Tags: c, maven, jenkins

I use jenkins+maven to compile a easy c program, but I got error message like that:

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\ljc\.jenkins\workspace\ljc_test\pom.xml integration-test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building NAR Executable Test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- nar-maven-plugin:3.2.0:nar-validate (default-nar-validate) @ it0001-executable ---
[INFO] Using AOL: amd64-Windows-msvc
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.333 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-15T14:26:23+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/219M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.maven-nar:nar-maven-plugin:3.2.0:nar-validate (default-nar-validate) on project it0001-executable: Could not launch cmd.exe /X /C "link /?": Error while executing process. Cannot run program "link": CreateProcess error=2, ????????? -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]    http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\ljc\.jenkins\workspace\ljc_test\pom.xml to ljc_test/it0001-executable/1.0-SNAPSHOT/it0001-executable-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Anybody can help me out? I've been there for a long time.

Comment: You tried running jenkins and maven in administrator mode? The error states quite clearly that maven is unable to launch the cmd.exe.